# Why is my Spring Security Voter only called at login, not for every page access?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have successfully created a custom AccessDecisionVoter class and tied it into my web application through XML.

Now I want this to be called with every page load, to make sure the user is allowed to access that specific page, not just the web site as a whole. It looks like my voter is only getting called when I log in.

How do I get it to be called with every page?

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true" 
               use-expressions="true" 
               access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/statics/*" access="permitAll" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                         default-target-url="/index" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                     logout-success-url="/loggedout"
                     logout-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.tarigma.gem.security.DBVoter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be called every request unless a previous filter in the security chain granted access.

Have you configured Spring as per request validation. Place this filter first in the chain. Most of the times the remember me overrides this. Take a look at what resources are configured to be checked.
You must configure under which uris are you performing the security.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Are you using annotations?

`<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>`

Comment: I believe that this will solve my problem, but I admit the whole Spring Security filter chain is something I don't understand. I added my security XML to my question, is there anything you can tell me to point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is only being called when I submit the log in form at `/login`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, which largely depend on the behavior you want.

1. If you want the check performed every time the user accesses any page, you will want to [create a custom filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) and check with your voter upon each request. Presumably you would need some logic to do this only if the user is already logged in, etc. and would need to take appropriate action (redirecting the user etc). You'd have to be careful here of infinite loops, and/or getting the filter to apply to only certain paths (for example, you wouldn't -- obviously -- protect the login form in this way).
2. You could use the [Spring Security tag library](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) - if you are using JSP for your views - to protect each page that you care about, using the `authorize` tag in the tag library, and checking with the role (or whatever string you have defined) that your Voter can vote on.

Either one of these would work fine, I don't think you'll find anything in the baseline Spring Security that will always authenticate users with every request - it's an operating assumption in the framework that once a user is authenticated and their authorization identified (at login time), it probably won't change.

Hope that helps!